# How to vertically split a dual widescreen into four virtual workspaces on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, display, multiple-monitors, xinerama

I have dual widescreen setup on Ubuntu using twinview (Nvidia).  I would like to split each monitor into two "virtual" screens, so at the end I get four virtual screens.

I could arrange my windows manually, but I'd like to be able to maximize a window and have it only consume half the monitor, and have its pop up dialogs centered on its half-screen.

I tired using using 'fakexinerama'  (http://ktown.kde.org/~seli/fakexinerama/) for that as another post suggested, however I cannot get the second to work with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you're using TwinView, it's likely you've disabled Xinerama.  As such, `fakexinerama` won't work, since it works as its name implies: by "faking" the Xinerama information.  If Xinerama is disabled, it doesn't matter what the Xinerama information says, it's just being ignored.

[Using fakexinerama](https://superuser.com/questions/115076/115158#115158) really seems to be the only game in town for doing what you (and I) want to do.  (I'm using it to split two widescreens into four page-sized screens under [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/).)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a tiling window manager: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager . They tend to be highly configurable, and are designed for the kind of purpose you seem to be looking for.

I've used a number of them, and can highly recommend [XMonad](http://www.xmonad.org/), [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/), or [wmii](http://wmii.suckless.org/)